# hi,how to achieve this in regex?

Tags: regex, string, trim

i have a string as 'US201112345' - i want to get result as 'US1112345'.if the string contains more than  10 letter then trim 4th and 5th letter

Comment: What language (if any) are you using with your regex?  Have you tried to solve this yourself before you posted here?

Comment: Please show the line of work to extend. And change the title

Comment: Is there some reason you need to use a regex instead of an if statement?

Comment: i want to do this in regex only

Answer (score 1):

If your unfamiliar working with regex why not just parse the string yourself?

Also you said remove the 4th and 5th letter but in the output example you removed 3rd and 4th but really I think your looking for 2nd and 3rd because first character of input string resides at 0 index like inputstring[0]

```
`string inputstring = Console.ReadLine();
        string outputstring = "";
        if (inputstring.Length > 10)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < inputstring.Length; i++)
            {
                if (i != 2 && i != 3)
                {
                    outputstring = outputstring + inputstring[i];
                }
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine(outputstring);`
```

There are other ways to but I feel like logic would be harder another good way is.substring.

```
string inputstring = Console.ReadLine();
        string outputstring = "";
        Int32 nvar = inputstring.Length-4;
        if (inputstring.Length > 10)
        {
            string firstpart = inputstring.Substring(0, 2);
            string secondpart = inputstring.Substring(4, nvar);
            outputstring = firstpart + secondpart;
        }
        Console.WriteLine(outputstring);
```

Hope that helps you solve what your trying to do.

Comment: string inputstring = Console.ReadLine();
        string outputstring = "";
        if (inputstring.Length > 10)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < inputstring.Length; i++)
            {
                if (i != 2 && i != 3)
                {
                    outputstring = outputstring + inputstring[i];
                }
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine(outputstring);`

Comment: the above code is working fine,but i want to do that in regex only